# What's going under the hood during .map(&:reload)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

We're using ActiveAdmin on our Rails App that has a Box model among others. Whenever an array of boxes (think a Box model with arbitrary, irrelevant attributes) is updated (I'm using `.update_all` on the array as opposed to `.update` in a loop over the array), we wish to create a log of attribute change on each box (we're using the public activity gem for this), which requires the freshly updated Box data. One of the strategies I came across to ensure not passing stale data from the in-memory array to the logging method was to call `.map(&:reload)` on the array before logging.

While this does solve the problem, I'm curious if this makes N fetch queries on the DB, as otherwise a better option seems to be to do a `Box.find(id: <array_of_ids>)` and then call the logging method on each object. Which is more advised to avoid avoidable DB hits?

Comment: you should be able to see in your console if it does N+1 query; it will show many nearly identical queries firing in succession. I'm pretty sure it does, in which case your alternative would be a better approach.

Comment: If you're going to reload each element individually, do `.each(&:reload)`, not `map`.

Answer (score 0):

`collection.map(&:reload)` is just a shortcut to the following code:

```
collection.map do |item|
  item.reload
end
```

There's even a name for the (&:method) notation: "Ruby Pretzel Syntax". So in this case it would do an n+1.

A better approach would be to call `reload` directly on your `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
collection = MyModel.where(...)

# do some stuff that would change a part of the resulting query..

collection.reload
```

This way, the query will be executed again and will assign the new results to your `collection` variable.

Or if your collection is an array, build a query yourself. e.g:

```
MyModel.where(id: collection.map(&:id))
```